# Имеются ли серьёзные лингвистические исследования волжской топонимики?

Tags: топонимика

Меня интересуют исследования не финно-угорских, а греческих топонимов Поволжья.

Answer (score 1):

Греков для того, чтоб называть что-либо, вообще в Поволжье  никогда не было. Названий именно топонимов, как-то связанных с исходными греческими словами, как-то и нет в бассейне Волги.

Comment: Тем не менее у Фасмера находим следующее замечание: *Древнейшее название Волги – `Ρᾶ у **Птолемея***.